# Is instanceof considered bad practice? If so, under what circumstances is instanceof still preferable?

Tags: java, instanceof

Over the years, I've tried to avoid `instanceof` whenever possible. Using polymorphism or the visitor pattern where applicable. I suppose it simply eases maintenance in some situations... Are there any other drawbacks that one should be aware of?

I do however see it here and there in the Java libraries so I suppose it has its place? Under what circumstances is it preferable? Is it ever unavoidable?

Comment: I have been investigating this same topic for other purposes and I found the following references to be really good. - [Prefer polymorphism over instanceof and downcasting](http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html) - [instanceof versus getClass in equals Methods](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch17.html) (Interview with Josh Bloch) - [Polymorphism and Interfaces](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html) (see section about When to use instanceof)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can imagine some cases, for example you have some objects of a library, which you can't extend (or it would be inconvenient to do so), perhaps mixed with some objects of your, all with same base class, together in a collection.
I suppose that in such case, using instanceof to distinguish some processing on these objects might be useful.

Idem in some maintenance of legacy code where you cannot inject some new behavior in lot of old classes just to add a new little feature or some bug fix...

Comment: I think in general, instanceof is most useful when dealing with APIs or libraries that you don't control.

Comment: Ok, so due to legacy code. Fair enough. Still, it feels like such use of instanceof "fixes" previously not completely throught through design decisions.

Answer (score 24):

It's definitely has its place in a stock implementation of `equals`. E.g.

```
public boolean equals ( Object o )
{
  if ( this == o )
  {
     return true;
  }

  if ( ! (o instanceof MyClass) )
  {
    return false;
  }

  // Compare fields
  ...
}
```

One neat thing to know about instanceof is that its LHS can be `null` and in that case the expression evaluates to `false`.

Comment: _that_ gives me the creeps for more than 10 years in the code base I have to work with.  Equality should not be defined (in most cases) on the type of objects, but on their behavior.  `MyClass` is an implementation that can behave totally equal as e.g. a sibling `CacheMyClass` object! I wish I could -2 you for it :)

Hmmm.... unless `instanceof` means 'implements' in this case, in which case it _may_ make sense...

Comment: I find the use of "instanceof" in equals() acceptable because it's impossible extend an instantiable class and add an aspect (e.g., a new field) while preserving the equals() contract (particularly symmetry and transitivity).  See Bloch's "Effective Java".

Comment: I prefer `getClass() == o.getClass()`. Otherwise a `Dog` may accidentally equal a `Pug` even though the `Pug` doesn't equal the `Dog`. If the class is final `instanceof` works fine of course, but then it's equivalent to class comparison anyway.

Comment: @aioobe.  Just remember, when doing class equality you DO have to check for `NULL` explicitly, as `NULL` is a valid parameter for `equals`.  <RANT>Implementing `equals` in the base class may be fraught with errors.  I would probably declare `Dog.equals` as `final` and delegate comparisong to a protected abstract template method `isDogEqual`.</RANT>

Comment: I think the use of `getClass()` is more prevalent and makes more sense in the manner @aioobe has mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

I think that when you absolutely need to know the type of an object, `instanceof` is the best option available.

A bad practice would be to have a lot of `instanceof`s, one next to the other, and according to them call different methods of the objects (of course casting).
This would probably reflect that the hierarchy needs rethinking and probably refactoring.

Answer (score 6):

When you are inside a pure OO model, then `instanceof` is definitely a code smell.

If, however, you are not using a 100% OO model or you need to inject stuff into it from the outside, then instanceof or equivalents (`isXXX()`, `getType()`, ...) can have its uses.

The general "rule" would be to avoid it whenever possible, especially when *you* control the type hierarchy and can use subtype polymorphism for example. The idea is not to ask the object what type it is and do something with it, but rather to ask the object directly or indirectly via a Visitor (essentially double polymorphism) to perform some action.

Answer (score 3):

I agree it can have a bad smell. Lots of instanceof, expecially in a chained together if block, smells of bad.

Sometimes it can behave in ways you would not expect... Something I had happen once:

```
Class B extends A
Class C extends A

B b = new B();
C c = new C();

b instanceof B -> true
b instanceof C -> true
c instanceof C -> true
c instanceof B -> true
```

(in my case this happened due to hibernate making proxy objects.... but just a case where code dpending on instanceof is risky)

Answer (score 2):

It can well be used as a sanity check before casting; in addition to checking that your object is of right type, it also does check that it's not null.

```
if (o instanceof MyThing) {
    ((MyThing) o).doSomething(); // This is now guaranteed to work.
} else {
    // Do something else, but don't crash onto ClassCast- or NullPointerException.
}
```

Comment: I know very well what it does. I would say that your example exhibits a *bad practice* of instanceof. I would probably want to eliminate that conditional using polymorphism as described [here](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Comment: @aioobe in equals(Object o) you don't know :)

Comment: Well, the example in that link is (in addition to being overly complex) prone to simple nullpointer crash. I prefer simple and robust solutions over fancy words.

Answer (score 0):

How about in the case of a creation factory?
e.g.

```
public static Cage createCage(Animal animal) {
  if (animal instanceof Dog)
    return new DogHouse();
  else if (animal instanceof Lion)
    return new SteelCage();
  else if (animal instanceof Chicken)
    return new ChickenWiredCage();
  else if (animal instanceof AlienPreditor)
    return new ForceFieldCage();
  ...
  else
    return new GenericCage();
}
```

Comment: I think I would prefer to have a `public abstract Cage getSuitableCage() { ... }` in `Animal`

Comment: I understand the desire to extend the class to take care of this behavior; though, it doesn't seem to scale well.  getSuitableCage is just one possible behavior that could be added.  There's a huge number of possible gets you might want.  eg. getSuitableHairBrush, getVetSpecialist, getSuitableBlanket, getSuitableBedding, getSuitableTrainer, etc.  The list can be quite large.  Adding them all to the Animal class could bloat the class.

Comment: It also assumes that you know apriori how the class might be used and forces everyone to implement everything, even if it doesn't make sense for what they are using the Animal for.  In addition it forces the Animal subclasses to know information that they may or may not know about and likely shouldn't need to know about.  It suddenly becomes a pain to implement the Animal class (especially if you need to serialize the object).  Again, I understand the desire to adhere to a more OO approach, but it just doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: I could see an alternative of creating a CagedAnimal inteface that extends the Animal interface.  You could then create a CagedDog that implements CagedAnimal and extends Dog.  This would present some ickyness on type checking (you can't just accept an Animal type, you have to accept a CagedAnimal), but it is a doable solution.  I still don't think it is worth it though.  A factory that uses instanceof seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: In that scenario, [the visitor pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930808/is-there-a-better-option-for-this-code) seems to be a better approach, no? (BTW, this is the classical discussion about the [expression problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem).)

Comment: I think I follow what you are suggesting; using typed method parameters to direct the Cage creation path.  Though, I don't quite see how to fit it into a creation factory into it.  If I have a creation method for each type of animal, then if I have an "Animal" object, the compiler can't figure out which creation method to call.  If I add a method that takes an "Animal" is will always be called instead of the concreted typed creation method.

Comment: The compiler can't figure it out (since Java is single dispatch), which is why you use a visitor pattern. You would do `Cage cage = someAnimal.accept(new CageFactoryVisitor());`.

Comment: Got it now. Had a mental block there.  Thanks for the patents in explaining it!