# How can I do a safe downcast and prevent a ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting, downcast

I have the following scenario:

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class C extends B {
    public void Foo();
}
```

I have a method that can return class **A**, **B** or **C** and I want to cast safely to C but only if the class type is **C**. This is because I need to call Foo() but I don't want the ClassCastException.

Comment: Before you go full-throttle into using `instanceof`, have a look at posts like this, as using `instanceof` is often a sign of a design flaw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instanc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790144/avoiding-instanceof-in-java

Comment: Consider using and interface, that way you'll get rid of all the nuances and restrictions imposed to you by the single inheritance model of java. public interface IFoo{ public void foo();}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you do this?

```
if (obj instanceof C) {
   ((C)obj).Foo();
}
else {
   // Recover somehow...
}
```

However, please see some of the other comments in this question, as over-use of `instanceof` is sometimes (not always) a sign that you need to rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider changing my design. It's just that it adds a lot of boilerplate to always use type C.

Comment: instanceof is like goto, if you use it then you need to take time and refactor your source :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check the type before casting using instanceof

```
Object obj = getAB_Or_C();

if ( obj instanceof C ) {
  C c = (C) obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is something like the following, then you don't need to cast.

```
public class A { 
    public void foo() {
        // default behaviour.
    }
} 

public class B extends A { 
} 

public class C extends B { 
    public void foo() {
       // implementation for C.
    }
}
```

Comment: SOmetimes, sometimes not. It doesn't always make sense for A to have a method foo(), and you might not be able to change the class A.

Comment: I can't change class A - it's part of GWT UI package.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `instanceof`, consider

```
interface Fooable { void foo(); }

class A implements Fooable { ... }
```