# How to avoid large if-statements and instanceof

Tags: java, casting, iteration

**Animal**

```
public abstract class Animal {
 String name;

 public Animal(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

}
```

**Lion**

```
public class Lion extends Animal {

 public Lion(String name) {
  super(name);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public void roar() {
  System.out.println("Roar");
 }
}
```

**Deer**

```
public class Deer extends Animal {

 public Deer(String name) {
  super(name);
 }

 public void runAway() {
  System.out.println("Running...");
 }

}
```

**TestAnimals**

```
public class TestAnimals {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Animal lion = new Lion("Geo");
  Animal deer1 = new Deer("D1");
  Animal deer2 = new Deer("D2");

  List<Animal> li = new ArrayList<Animal>();
  li.add(lion);
  li.add(deer1);
  li.add(deer2);
  for (Animal a : li) {
   if (a instanceof Lion) {
    Lion l = (Lion) a;
    l.roar();
   }
   if (a instanceof Deer) {
    Deer l = (Deer) a;
    l.runAway();
   }

  }
 }
}
```

Is there a better way to iterate through the list without having to cast ?In the above case it seem's ok but if you have many extensions of the base class then we'll need that many if block too.Is there a design pattern or principle to address this problem ?

Comment: Do the methods have to have different names (roar, runAway)?

The idea of polymorphism is having the same methods in the subclasses, with the JVM calling the appropiate one.

Comment: Is there a better way to do a wrong thing?

Comment: What's the *intent* of the code in `TestAnimals`? Is it 'do the animal-specific thing to each animal'? Or '`roar` all `Lion`s, `runAway` all `Deer`' and nothing more?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An elegant way of avoiding `instanceof` without inventing some new artificial method in the base class (with a non-descriptive name such as `performAction` or `doWhatYouAreSupposedToDo`) is to **use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)**. Here is an example:

**Animal**

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class Animal {
    String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract void accept(AnimalVisitor av);  // <-- Open up for visitors.

}
```

**Lion** and **Deer**

```
class Lion extends Animal {
    public Lion(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public void roar() {
        System.out.println("Roar");
    }

    public void accept(AnimalVisitor av) {
        av.visit(this);                            // <-- Accept and call visit.
    }
}


class Deer extends Animal {

    public Deer(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void runAway() {
        System.out.println("Running...");
    }

    public void accept(AnimalVisitor av) {
        av.visit(this);                            // <-- Accept and call visit.
    }

}
```

**Visitor**

```
interface AnimalVisitor {
    void visit(Lion l);
    void visit(Deer d);
}

class ActionVisitor implements AnimalVisitor {

    public void visit(Deer d) {
        d.runAway();
    }

    public void visit(Lion l) {
        l.roar();
    }
}
```

**TestAnimals**

```
public class TestAnimals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal lion = new Lion("Geo");
        Animal deer1 = new Deer("D1");
        Animal deer2 = new Deer("D2");

        List<Animal> li = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        li.add(lion);
        li.add(deer1);
        li.add(deer2);
        for (Animal a : li)
            a.accept(new ActionVisitor());         // <-- Accept / visit.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, tend to agree. I can't resist voting up visitor. I love it, but I think you do more than I do. +1

Comment: Its regarding the description you added later, with visitor adding any new `Animal` will require modification of `AnimalVisitor`. Whereas, the other option is good to go without this kinda modification. What say you?

Comment: @Adeel Ansari, That a good point. It depends on the situation I'd say. It depends on if you want the specific action-implementations to be collected in one class, or if you want them scattered in the different classes. Both are preferable in different situations. In this scenario however, `roar` and `runAway` are so different that I wouldn't want to invent a common name for the two.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do the implementation of the accept method in the parent class (Animal)?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. This is because the method signature is determined in compile time, while the target type is in this case determined at runtime.

Comment: Actually, instanceof is preferable to this visitor pattern for pretty much every reason: 1. Surprise, instanceof is faster! 2. Instanceof is more readable 3. The visitor pattern is not as intuitive.  I'm posting an example in an answer...

Comment: @aioobe: do you consider this pattern more readable, maintainable, or safe than instanceof?  If so, why?

Comment: @aioobe the one example of improved maintainability I can think of is, if a developer creates a new Animal type, and if they think to add a method for the new type to AnimalVisitor, they will immediately get errors showing all places that don't do something for that type of Animal.

Comment: No @Andy, I assure you that the instanceof is not preferable to the visitor pattern. In fact instanceof is most often considered code smell. (Many answers here at SO confirms this stand point.) (1) smells like premature optimization (and is probably even slower if there are many classes) (2) Maybe true for an OOP-newbie. In certain scenarios though, the visitor pattern is much more readable (I'm thinking of cases where you subclass the visitor, possibly in an anonymous class). (3) uhm.. that's just a repetition of (2).

Comment: What do you mean premature optimization?  There was nothing I was trying to optimize; instanceof just happens to be faster.  I think part of the idea that instanceof is a "code smell" has come from worries that it performs badly, so I wanted to clear that up.

Comment: OOP literacy aside, how can more lines of code/extra classes to do something ever be more readable?

Comment: @Andy I have to say that your code for "compared 3 methods" is not acceptable. Why putting 3 method calls in one main method and run visitor first? Change the order calling these 3 method and then get a different result. My run result shows Visitor Pattern is faster.

Comment: Change the order how?  In any case I'm not expecting `instanceof` to always be faster, I was mainly just trying to put the old fear that `instanceof` is slow to death.

Comment: @aioobe another thing worth mentioning is that a visitor pattern unfortunately can't be used when you don't control the entire class hierarchy.  For instance, there's no way to patch a visitor pattern onto Swing `Component`s.

Answer (score 13):

**Animal**

```
public abstract class Animal {
 String name;

 public Animal(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public abstract void exhibitNaturalBehaviour();

}
```

**Lion**

```
public class Lion extends Animal {

 public Lion(String name) {
  super(name);
 }

 public void exhibitNaturalBehaviour() {
  System.out.println("Roar");
 }
}
```

**Deer**

```
public class Deer extends Animal {

 public Deer(String name) {
  super(name);
 }

 public void exhibitNaturalBehaviour() {
  System.out.println("Running...");
 }

}
```

**TestAnimals**

```
public class TestAnimals {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Animal[] animalArr = {new Lion("Geo"), new Deer("D1"), new Deer("D2")};
  for (Animal a : animalArr) {
     a.exhibitNaturalBehaviour();    
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Also, this could easily be extended to use a strategy pattern. Supplying in the action to take place (with a separate setter, or in constructor) upon doWhatYouSupposeToDo(). Although it might be better to call it act() or perform()

Comment: @Steven: I tend to agree, with both of your suggestions. I just came up with this name arbitrarily. Yes, it sounds stupid and cute ;D.

Comment: Proposed alternative method name: exhibitNaturalBehaviour()

Comment: @Mikera: Modified to rename the method. Thanks.

Comment: It's just an example of the old good polymorphism. And it's cool, unless you want to have some *external behaviour* that is not nailed to your data-structure.

Answer (score 5):

Yes provide a method called `action()` in abstract class , implement it in both of the child class, one will roar other will runaway

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching support in the language eliminates the need for the ugly visitor pattern.

See this Scala code for example:

```
abstract class Animal(name: String)

class Lion(name: String) extends Animal(name) {
  def roar() {
    println("Roar!")
  }
}

class Deer(name: String) extends Animal(name) {
  def runAway() {
    println("Running!")
  }
}

object TestAnimals {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val animals = List(new Lion("Geo"), new Deer("D1"), new Deer("D2"))
    for(animal <- animals) animal match {
      case l: Lion => l.roar()
      case d: Deer => d.runAway()
      case _       => ()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Emil: 'a' is simply a label assigned to the object matched on that case.

Comment: @Emil: It's exactly equivalent to your Java way (`instanceof` and then cast). Pattern matching just makes it syntactically nicer. :)

Answer (score 2):

If your method is not polymorphic you can't do without the cast. To make it polymorphic, declare a method in the base class and override it in the descendant classes.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a `List` of animals. Usually when you have a list of Objects, all these objects must be able to do the same thing without being casted.

So the best two solutions are :

- Having a common method for the two concrete classes (so defined as `abstract` in `Animal`)
- Separate `Lion` from `Deer` from the start, and have two different lists.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that instanceof is faster than the visitor pattern presented above; I think this should make us question, is the visitor pattern really more elegant than instanceof when it's doing the same thing more slowly with more lines of code?

Here's my test.  I compared 3 methods: the visitor pattern above, instanceof, and an explicit type field in Animal.

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, 64-bit
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80 GHz 2.93 GHz
RAM: 8.00 GB
JRE: 1.7.0_21-b11, 32-bit

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnimalTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal lion = new Lion("Geo");
        Animal deer1 = new Deer("D1");
        Animal deer2 = new Deer("D2");

        List<Animal> li = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        li.add(lion);
        li.add(deer1);
        li.add(deer2);

        int reps = 10000000;

        long start, elapsed;

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (Animal a : li)
                a.accept(new ActionVisitor()); // <-- Accept / visit.
        }
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

        System.out.println("Visitor took " + elapsed + " ns");

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (Animal a : li) {
                if (a instanceof Lion) {
                    ((Lion) a).roar();
                } else if (a instanceof Deer) {
                    ((Deer) a).runAway();
                }
            }
        }
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

        System.out.println("instanceof took " + elapsed + " ns");

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (Animal a : li) {
                switch (a.type) {
                case Animal.LION_TYPE:
                    ((Lion) a).roar();
                    break;
                case Animal.DEER_TYPE:
                    ((Deer) a).runAway();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

        System.out.println("type constant took " + elapsed + " ns");
    }
}

abstract class Animal {
    public static final int LION_TYPE = 0;
    public static final int DEER_TYPE = 1;

    String name;
    public final int type;

    public Animal(String name, int type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public abstract void accept(AnimalVisitor av); // <-- Open up for visitors.
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    public Lion(String name) {
        super(name, LION_TYPE);
    }

    public void roar() {
        // System.out.println("Roar");
    }

    public void accept(AnimalVisitor av) {
        av.visit(this); // <-- Accept and call visit.
    }
}

class Deer extends Animal {

    public Deer(String name) {
        super(name, DEER_TYPE);
    }

    public void runAway() {
        // System.out.println("Running...");
    }

    public void accept(AnimalVisitor av) {
        av.visit(this); // <-- Accept and call visit.
    }

}

interface AnimalVisitor {
    void visit(Lion l);

    void visit(Deer d);
}

class ActionVisitor implements AnimalVisitor {

    public void visit(Deer d) {
        d.runAway();
    }

    public void visit(Lion l) {
        l.roar();
    }
}
```

Test results:

Visitor took 920842192 ns
instanceof took 511837398 ns
type constant took 535296640 ns

This visitor pattern introduces 2 extra method calls that are unnecessary with instanceof.  This is probably why it's slower.

Not that performance is the only consideration, but notice how 2 instanceofs are faster than even a 2-case switch statement.  Plenty of people have worried about the performance of instanceof, but this should put the worry to rest.

As a Java Developer, I feel frustrated when people have a dogmatic attitude about avoiding the use of instanceof, because there have been several times in my work I wanted to clean up or write new clean code by using instanceof, but coworkers/superiors didn't approve of this approach , because they have more or less blindly accepted the idea that instanceof should never be used.  I feel frustrated because this point is often driven home with toy examples that don't reflect real business concerns.

Whenever you pursue modular software design, there will always be times when type-dependent decisions need to be isolated from the types in question, so that the types have as few dependencies as possible.

This visitor pattern doesn't break modularity, but it's not a superior alternative to instanceof.

Comment: I think it's fair to bring this up.  However in the vast majority cases, ease of maintenance will far outweigh a modest performance gain.  With the visitor pattern, adding a new type of animal will expose immediately any places that need to be updated, as any previously existing visitors will now fail to compile.  If-else chains using instanceof will happily compile and there is a good chance that you will not discover you have effected the foreign module until the incorrect behavior is noticed.

Comment: @derekv Where do you think instanceof is more appropriate?  Say that java.lang.Number had been written with a visitor pattern.  Would it really be worth writing a visitor every time you want to check the type of a Number instance?  Especially if you only wanted to do something if it was a Double, for instance?
Also, if you're making a library, and intend for users to be able to extend a type in your library for which you've created a visitor pattern, users of your library would not be able to add a method for their new type to the visitor interface in your library, unless they want to fork.

Comment: I don't think there's one solution that will work best for every situation, what I advocate is a best effort in knowing what tools you have, and make a decision which best meets the needs of the problem being solved, and respect for those who will maintain the code later.  Almost everywhere I've seen `instanceof` in application code it's a smell and not a performance critical loop or such. I'm aware of several problems with the visitor pattern as well.  As for your library question, I'd need to see some specifics, but it's an interesting point, it might make a good separate question.

Comment: @derekv I've definitely seen some `instanceof` code smells too.  I didn't bring up performance because I think it's a big deal, more because there's a historical fear that `instanceof` is inefficient underlying some of the arguments against it, and I wanted to dispel that fear.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding an interface for the action (Roar, Run away, etc) which is set on the animal in the constructor. Then have an abstract method such as act() on the Animal class which gets called similar to what Adeel has.

This will let you swap in actions to act out via a field at any time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to have the super class implement a default behaviour.

```
public enum AnimalBehaviour { 
     Deer { public void runAway() { System.out.println("Running..."); } },
     Lion { public void roar() { System.out.println("Roar"); } }
     public void runAway() { } 
     public void roar() { }
 } 

 public class Animal {
     private final String name;
     private final AnimalBehaviour behaviour;
     public Animal(String name, AnimalBehaviour behaviour) {
         this.name = name;
         this.behaviour = behaviour;
     }
     public void runAway() { behaviour.runAway(); } 
     public void roar() { behaviour.roar(); }
  }

 public class TestAnimals { 
   public static void main(String... args) { 
     Animal[] animals = { 
       new Animal("Geo", AnimalBehaviour.Lion), 
       new Animal("Bambi", AnimalBehaviour.Deer), 
       new Animal("D2", AnimalBehaviour.Deer) 
     }; 

     for (Animal a : animals) {
       a.roar(); 
       a.runAway(); 
     } 
   }
 }
```

Comment: The use of Enum in this case is not very flexible, as there will only exist a single Deer behaviour instance. (The Deer behaviour can thus not, for instance, have a reference to the related deer-object, as the behaviour is shared with other Deer instances.) Besides, it's not very elegant to be able to write myDeer.roar().

Comment: You should only need one Deer behviour as it is intended to describe all deers. If you need a more complicated structure you can't use enum alone. But I wouldn't start assuming a problem is more complicated than it needs to be. You should always strive for the simplest solution which meets your needs.