# instanceof versus polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am having troubles with the `instanceof` operator.  I'm trying to avoid it.  Basically, I have the following structure:

```
class Shape {}
class Triangle extends Shape {}
class Rectangle extends Shape {}

ShapeParser s;
while (s.hasNext())
     parseShape(s.next()); // returns a Shape object

void parseShape(Triangle t) { // do stuff } // KEY POINT HERE
void parseShape(Rectangle t) { // etc }
```

The key point I'm making is: I want to do a parameter overload of the function, but it's not working as I intend it to (compile-error).  I am trying to avoid:

```
void parseShape(Shape s)
{
     if (s instanceof Triangle) ...
}
```

UPDATE: it seems that the consensus is to create a base class method: parseShape() to do the 
lifting.  I wanted to clarify my question: the motivation of this question is relative to the observer pattern.  Suppose I have the following Observer object payload method:

```
    public void update(Observable obj, Shape objectPayload){} 
// note: the objectPayload is usually of type Object
```

Instead of performing:

```
public void update(Observable obj, Shape objectPayload)
{
       if (objectPayload instanceof Triangle)
          // do stuff
       else if (objectPayload instanceof Rectangle)
          // etc
}
```

I want to do:

```
public void update(Observable obj, Shape objectPayload)
{
       parseShape(objectPayload);
}

    void parseShape(Triangle t) {  } // do stuff
    void parseShape(Rectangle t) { }
```

Comment: Please post the error...

Comment: And why is your rectangle called `t`? :-)

Comment: No, no, a hundred times no! Don't make me come over there and slap you around :-) In OO, the _object/class_ is god. If you find yourself in the situation where _code_ is once again becoming the primary thing, you're reverting to the pre-OO days. Even the observer pattern should follow this rule: ... notifies them automatically of any state changes, _usually by calling one of their methods._

Comment: Looks more and more like you want the visitor pattern. See, for example, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944824/visitor-pattern-implementation-in-java-how-does-this-look). Put that once into your Shape hierarchy and you won't need to pollute that hierarchy with parsing code, or code for any other operation you want to apply similarly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the `parseShape` into each Shape class. Alternatively, you can use the Visitor pattern. There's a neat trick with reflection shown in the solution to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946408/generic-visitor-pattern-in-java) that avoids the complexity of a full visitor pattern in Java.

UPDATE:

Here's a recipe for the visitor pattern:

1. Declare an interface:

   ```
   public interface ShapeVisitor {  
       visit(Triangle);  
       visit(Rectangle);  
       // ...  
   }
   ```
2. In `Shape`, declare an abstract method `acceptVisitor`:

   ```
   class Shape {
       public abstract void acceptVisitor(ShapeVisitor visitor);
   }
   ```
3. In each concrete class, implement `acceptVisitor`:

   ```
   class Triangle extends Shape {
       public void acceptVisitor(ShapeVisitor visitor) {
           visitor.visit(this);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Declare your `ParseVisitor` class to implement `ShapeVisitor` and implement all the required methods (simply rename each of the `parseShape` methods to `visit`).

The nice things about this are, first, it keeps the parsing code out of your Shape hierarchy and centralizes it in a separate parsing class; second, if you later decide that you need to do some other operation (like, say, render), you can apply the same pattern *without ever changing any Shape class*. The big down side of this approach is that you will have to change all classes that implement `ShapeVisitor` if you decide to add another `Shape` subclass.

Answer (score 4):

If your `parseShape()` method were declared in `Shape`, it could be overridden in `Triangle` and `Rectangle`.

That is:

```
ShapeParser s;
while (s.hasNext())
     // Calls the proper implementation of parseShape()
     s.next().parseShape();
```

Comment: +1. This is the correct OO way of doing it. Use of `instanceof` should usually be a tar-and-feather offence in your code reviews :-)

Comment: Your sort of turn the world inside out, and then it falls into place. +1 on tar-and-feather.

Answer (score 1):

Um, add a parse method to the base class then just loop and iterate through the list of shapes and call s.parse()?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the error is because s.next() returns Shape. Logical thing would be 
to add parse() method to shape and call s.parse()