# General Polymorphism with PHP examples

Tags: php, polymorphism

As only Dogs can play "fetch", is this example a good or a bad idea? I suspect it's a really bad idea due to the usage of instanceof, but I'm not entirely sure why.

```
class Animal {
    var $name;
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    function speak() {
        return "Woof, woof!";
    }

    function playFetch() {
        return 'getting the stick';
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    function speak() {
        return "Meow...";
    }
}

$animals = array(new Dog('Skip'), new Cat('Snowball'));

foreach($animals as $animal) {
    print $animal->name . " says: " . $animal->speak() . '<br>';
    if ($animal instanceof Dog) echo $animal->playFetch();
}
```

Another example. As I am constantly creating data objects that have an ID, I figured I might as well extend them all from a base class to avoid code duplication. Again, this was bad right? As a Chair doesn't have a name and a Dog doesn't have wheels. But they **are** both Data Objects so it's very confusing.

```
class Data_Object {
    protected $_id;

    function setId($id) {
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    function getId() {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}

class Dog extends Data_Object {
    protected $_name;
    function setName($name) {
        $this->_name = 
    }

    function getName() {
        return $this->_name;
    }
}

class Chair extends Data_Object {
    protected $_numberOfWheels;
    function setNumberOfWheels($number) {
        $this->_numberOfWheels = $number;
    }

    function getNumberOfWheels() {
        return $this->_numberOfWheels;
    }
}
```

Essentially what I *think* I'm asking is: **"should all subclasses have the same interface or can they have different ones?"**

Comment: Pretty sure this has been asked here before, but the short answer is it's OK for subclasses to have a different interface.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first example is not right due to the use of instanceof for conditional logic. Isn't the entire point of Polymorphism not to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to get all animals to do something (speak), except for one kind (Dog)? Sounds like the faulty logic is in the loop, not the class definitions.

Comment: They all speak, including the dog. But only the dog can play fetch. Either way I think I might have found something helpful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119087/instanceof-versus-polymorphism

Comment: If two different objects can do the same thing in different ways, that's polymorphism. If an object can *additionally* do something else, well, so be it. That's just not a polymorphic behavior then, since it's behavior unique to the object. You just wouldn't treat that specific behavior as polymorphic then.

Comment: @deceze that makes perfect sense, thank you. This applies perfectly to my second example. I think my first one is still very misguided as I've just read this quote from Scott Meyers: "Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do something else," slap yourself."

Comment: `Data_Object` sounds like a bad class-name. Probably `ModelAbstract` is more fitting.

Comment: I think if you have a check of instanceof to play fetch, it should be changed to `$animal->canPlayFetch()`

Comment: FTR, the title is misleading. deceze's answer in comments answered the general question about polymorphism, where as the question and accepted answer were geared towards a specific example.

Comment: This site have a very good explanation and practice examples http://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials/polymorphism-in-php // http://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials/polymorphism-in-php/practice

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In this context it's useful to talk about *interfaces*.

```
interface Talkative {
    public function speak();
}

class Dog extends Animal implements Talkative {
    public function speak() {
        return "Woof, woof!";
    }
}
```

Any animal *or human* (or alien) that implements the Talkative interface can be used in a context where talkative beings are needed:

```
protected function makeItSpeak(Talkative $being) {
    echo $being->speak();
}
```

This is a properly used polymorphic method. You don't care *what* you're dealing with as long as it can `speak()`.

If `Dog`s can also play fetch, that's great for them. If you want to generalize that, think about it in terms of an interface as well. Maybe one day you'll get a highly trained cat which can play fetch as well.

```
class Cog extends Cat implements Playfulness {
    public function playFetch() { ... }
}
```

The important point here being that when you *call* `playFetch()` on something, it's because you want to play fetch with that animal. You don't call `playFetch` because, well... you can, but because you want to play fetch in this very moment. If you don't want to play fetch, then you don't call it. If you need to play fetch in a certain situation, then you need something that can play fetch. You ensure this through interface declarations.

You can achieve the same thing using class inheritance, it's just less flexible. In some situations where rigid hierarchies exist though it's perfectly useful:

```
abstract class Animal { }

abstract class Pet extends Animal { }

class Dog extends Pet {
    public function playFetch() { ... }
}

class GermanShepherd extends Dog {
    public function beAwesome() { ... }
}
```

Then, in some specific context, you may not require *any object* that can do something (interface), but you are specifically looking for a `GermanShepherd`, because only it can be awesome:

```
protected function awesomeness(GermanShepherd $dog) {
    $dog->beAwesome();
}
```

Maybe down the road you'll make a new breed of `GermanShepherd`s that are also awesome, but `extend` the `GermanShepherd` class. They'll still work with the `awesomeness` function, just like with interfaces.

What you certainly should not do is to loop through a bunch of random things, check what they are and make them do their own thing. That's just not very sensible in any context.

Comment: its refreshing to see a php developer talk about interfaces.  i use them alot in php, but in most major frameworks there is no love, and thus very low adoption of the ideology by the common php developer.

Comment: @deceze Great answer.But i wonder if traits are also worth-mentioning here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: @Muhammad Not really, IMO. Traits are not type hintable and therefore are somewhat irrelevant to the discussion.

Comment: I know it's old, but if my Dog can "breath", "walk", "jump", and so does my Cat, does that mean I have to implement all of these interfaces ? That's a lot of implements isn't it ?!

Comment: @Steve 1) You'd probably not create a single interface for each of those methods in practice, you'd create one interface which defines all three of those methods together. It's up to you to subdivide your interfaces into parts which make sense, which are neither too detailed nor too large and unrelated. 2) You can create composite interfaces, e.g. `interface Mammal extends Breathing, Walking, Jumping`.

Answer (score 29):

Another example for Polymorphism in PHP

```
    <?php
interface Shape {
   public function getArea();
}

class Square implements Shape {
   private $width;
   private $height;

   public function __construct($width, $height) {
      $this->width = $width;
      $this->height = $height;
   }

   public function getArea(){
      return $this->width * $this->height;
   }
}

class Circle implements Shape {
   private $radius;

   public function __construct($radius) {
      $this->radius = $radius;
   }

   public function getArea(){

      return 3.14 * $this->radius * $this->radius;
   }
}

function calculateArea(Shape $shape) {
   return $shape->getArea();
}

$square = new Square(5, 5);
$circle = new Circle(7);

echo calculateArea($square), "<br/>";
echo calculateArea($circle);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same as you Krishnadas, Brad. This article helped me alot in understanding how to handle polymorphism in PHP

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php--net-14362

```
interface shape_drawer{
    public function draw(Shape $obj);
}

class circle implements shape_drawer{
    public function draw(Shape $obj){
        echo "Drawing Circle, Area: {$obj->area} <br>";
    }
}

class square implements shape_drawer{
    public function draw(Shape $obj){
        echo "Drawing Square, Area: {$obj->area} <br>";
    }
}

class triangle implements shape_drawer{
    public function draw(Shape $obj){
        echo "Drawing Triangle, Area: {$obj->area} <br>";
    }    
}

class shape_factory{
    public static function getShape(){

        $shape = $_REQUEST['shape'];

        if(class_exists($shape)) {
            return new $shape();
        }
        throw new Exception('Unsupported format');
    }
}

class Shape{

    public function __construct($area){
        $this->area = $area;
    }
    public function draw(shape_drawer $obj) {
        return $obj->draw($this);
    }
}


$shape = new Shape(50);
try {
    $drawer = shape_factory::getShape();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $drawer = new circle();
}

echo $shape->draw($drawer);
```