# PHP polymorphism, arrays and looping

Tags: php, arrays, polymorphism

I am currently working on an API in PHP for my personal use and have created a design that relies heavily on the ability to tap into polymorphism. I frequently work with languages like C++, Java and Objective-C where polymorphism has more versatility.

I have noticed that PHP is a little more resistant to polymorphism and was wondering if someone knows the proper syntax for what I am attempting below:

```
// FIRST Create objects and store in variables
$link0 = new Link("#", "StackOverflow");
$link1 = new Link("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "StackOverflow");
$link2 = new Link("http://www.stackcareers.com", "StackCareers");

// Use 
$stack_submenu = new Menu( $link0, array( $link1,$link2 ) );
...
foreach ( $stack_submenu->menuItems as $item ) {
$item->html();
}
```

The above example gives me the follow error:

> Fatal Error - Call to a member function html() on a non-object

I read around and found a way to drop the error by changing the syntax, however, I MUST call the constructors to the Link Objects inside the array:

```
// WORKS, but does not allow me to use variables in place of constructor
$submenu_mamp = new Menu($link_mamp, array( new Link("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "StackOverflow"),  new Link("http://www.stackcareers.com", "StackCareers")));
```

The above works, but for the sake of my application, I construct the objects before constructing the array. I have tried passing by reference, but I get the same error stated earlier.

Is there anyway to do what I am trying, or do I have to directly call the constructor inside the array definition?

**EDIT**

Menu Class Constructor:

```
// CONSTRUCTOR
    public function __construct($menuLink, $menuItems) {
        // Set Properties
        $this->menuLink     = $menuLink;
        $this->menuItems    = $menuItems;   
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the Menu class constructor?

Comment: The first argument $menuLink takes in a Link object that is used as label for the Menu (using Bootstrap) and the second $menuItems is an array of Link Objects which are later used to display a submenu.

Comment: In Java or C++ I would just create an Array or Vector of type Link, but I'm not sure if PHP supports Type Hinting with Arrays.

Comment: But your error doesn't seem directly connected to type casting. Did you try to `var_dump($item)` inside the `foreach` and see what you get?

Comment: Maybe it can [help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542661/general-polymorphism-with-php-examples).