# differentiate between each children classes in an arraylist of parent class

Tags: java, arraylist

hi I have a parent class that is `Abstract Employee` and I have childrens `Secretary, Engineer, Technician` If i have `ArrayList<Employee> employees;` and in a for loop I have randomly made employee=new Secretary or  new Engineer...

Is there a way of knowing who's who ? apologies for my ignorance if the question wasn't well asked.

Comment: (Note that sometimes secretaries are promoted to engineers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, you should not care. If you need to do different things depending on which specific class it is, then it should go into a (possibly abstract) method in `Employee` which the subclasses override and implement differently. Then you just go through the list and call that method on every element.

This would be proper object oriented design.

Comment: Whatever you need each employee to do e.g. employee.work(). each employee knows what they need to do, not the caller/loop code.

Comment: yes that's what I was looking for "the proper O-O design" though I will dive into visitor pattern as others suggested :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` native operator.

Something like this:

```
List<Employee> yourList;
for (Employee e : yourList) {
    if (e instanceof Secretary) {
        Secretary s = (Secretary)e;
        // do something with s
    } else if (e instanceof Engineer) {
        Engineer eng = (Engineer)e;
        // do something with eng
    }
    // you get the idea...
}
```

Having said that, abusing use of `instanceof` is not always a good idea. You will have a cleaner more object oriented solution by using polymorphism in your class.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to implement the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) in situations like these.

You may also want to look at a complete example [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930808/is-there-a-better-option-for-this-code/3930863#3930863) **which solves this precise problem** in the context of a list of `Animal`s extended by `Lion`s and `Deer`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use `instanceof`, but it will defeat the purpose of your design.  Every time you add another subtype of Employee you'll have to modify potentially lots of code - every place that operates on this list.

Another way to do it that could reduce the number of changes (or at least keep them in one manageable place) is to use a Visitor pattern or polymorphism to let code figure out what to do based on type at runtime.