# why overloading does not support polymorphism

Tags: java

```
public class Ex
{
  public void eat(Animal animal){System.out.println("this is animal");}
  public void eat(Dog dog){System.out.println("this is dog");}
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       Ex ex=new Ex();
       Animal animal=new Dog();
       ex.eat(animal);
  }
}
```

why this program gives output:this is animal rather than this is dog because actual instance is Dog at runtime

Comment: The principles of polymorphism would have `eat()` be a class method of `Animal` that `Dog` could override. This way you don't have to write overloaded methods, the object is the one deciding how it functions.

Comment: @unholysampler, sure, that solves it partially, but suppose you have four methods: `eat(Animal a, Spagetti s)`, `eat(Animal a, Pizza p)`, `eat(Dog d, Spagetti s)` and `eat(Dog d, Pizza p)`.

Comment: @aioobe: Code like that is a highway to hell. JUst do: `Animal.eat(Food)`, where Animal and Food are abstract classes for Dog and Spaghetti aand Pizza

Comment: Then you can `eat(Food f)` and allow the food to give you information about what you want to do. It's an exercise in finding the common interfaces and utilizing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is decided in *compile time* which method to call.

In general the compiler can't decide the runtime type of a variable (it's undecidable), so the compiler plays it safe and makes a call to the method which it is sure will "work".

The standard "work-around" is to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). I have written a detailed example over here: [How to avoid large if-statements and instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930808/is-there-a-better-option-for-this-code/3930863#3930863)

Comment: ok i know that overloading methods are called only by using the reference type not the actual instance it refers to..why the java designers avoid polymorphism for overloading

Comment: @saravanan, I don't know for sure, but I bet the main reason would be performance. Also, the way it works internally is that a method is identified by name + argument types. That is, your two eat-methods are completely different from the JVMs point of view. (What I'm trying to say is that I'm not even sure it would make sense from this perspective.)

Answer (score 0):

Because java does not support [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).. But you can simulate double dispatch behaviour by means of [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).