# Pick objects of a certain subclass, and loop through them?

Tags: java, collections

I am writing an application in Java. I was wondering if there is a way to iterate only over objects of a certain subclass in a Collection (in my case an ArrayList). I'm aware that i can use ***instanceof*** and only work with the objects which are made from that class. And I also know that I can create a second ArrayList where I put the objects of that specific class, and iterate over that one. But it would be very convenient if i could "select" which subclass to iterate over.

Comment: Isn't `instanceof` an imperative-style selection?

Comment: It's not a correction so much as I don't see what you are asking since `instanceof` does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would typically use `instanceof` (or `getClass()`). That being said, these approaches are not very OOP idiomatic and rarely the best approach.

I would suggest that you either

1. Create a method in the super class (with an empty default implementation) overridden by the class you want to iterate over and call that for every object in your collection, or
2. use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) though. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930808/how-to-avoid-large-if-statements-and-instanceof/3930863#3930863) comes pretty close to what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, the first option was really simple and nice, didn't really think of that option.

Comment: Sure. I think the second option is the most elegant and OOP idiomatic. Let me know if you like me to expand on the second option.

Comment: I definitely like the second one also after looking closer. What would be the greatest advantages with this method compared to call individually implemented methods of every subclass?

Comment: The advantage of method 2 is that you don't have to create a possibly ill placed method in the super class. If you want all Dogs in your Animal collection to bark, you don't have to put `public void bark() {}` in the Animal class. You would do `myList.forEach(animal -> animal.accept(new BarkVisitor()))` and the `BarkVisitor` would only take action when visiting a Dog object. (All without any instanceof checks!)

Comment: Which would mean that in theory you could choose only to a call a method of one subclass, and leave the other subclasses out?

Comment: Yes. Each animal would call `visitor.visit(this)` and the visitor would call `bark()` only if the argument (`this`) is a Dog. It's a fairly neat trick once you've wrapped your head around it. I need to go to bed... God natt ;-)

Comment: Seems very useful in cases like mine. God natt!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8's streams to filter the correct class:

```
myList.stream().filter(o -> o instanceof SpecificClass).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will print out only the objects of SpecificClass. If you have the class you want to select by in variable, you can do:

```
Class<? extends Object> classToSelect = SpecificClass.class;
myList.stream().filter(classToSelect::isInstance).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: *[...] I'm aware that i can use instanceof [...]*

Comment: So using java 8's new Collections features you are actually capable to express internal iteration? I think this is the solution i was looking for.

Comment: The syntax is nice, but in the end it's not a better design than a for loop and instanceof-check (i.e. not very OOP idiomatic).