# Java directing object of type superclass to appropriate method

Tags: java

In my Java code I have a class 'Feature' which is extended by 'ContinuousFeature' and 'DiscreteFeature'. I have methods:

```
Calculate(ContinuousFeature c)
```

and

```
Calculate(DiscreteFeature d)
```

I have an ArrayList containing generic 'Feature' objects (both Discrete and Continuous), and am trying to do something like:

```
for(Feature f : features) {

    Calculate(f);

}
```

Hoping that they would automatically be directed to the appropriate method. However, IntelliJ is informing me that it cannot find a method Calculate for type 'Feature'. Any advice? :)

Comment: That's right. Method overloading is resolved at compile time. You'll have to resort to instance-of checks / casts, or something like the visitor pattern. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930808/how-to-avoid-large-if-statements-and-instanceof/3930863#3930863) (`Lion` corresponds to your `ContinuousFeature`, and `Deer` corresponds to your `DiscreteFeature`.)

Comment: The usual solution is to make `calculate` an instance method of `Feature` and override it in the 2 subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

You can change code like this.

```
for(Feature f : features) {
if(f instanceof ContinuousFeature)
    Calculate((ContinuousFeature)f);
else {
 Calculate((DiscreteFeature)f);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather avoid using instanceof

Comment: @MrD - between `instanceof` and "visitor pattern", I might choose `instanceof` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont like using `instanceof`, I suggest adding in methods like `isContinuousFeature()` in their respective classes returning a boolean type and checking each time, it may not be the cleanest but it will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could create in your Feature.java something like

```
public void Calculate(Feature feature){}
```

And I think that line could solve your problem.
Or maybe make the class abstract and something like:

```
public abstract void Calculate(Feature feature);
```

would be enough. And I think it would be cleaner. But that's just my opinion. Hope this helps.