# How to avoid unchecked cast when generic variable is resolved at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-safety

I have a parametrized value, that is resolved at runtime:

```
public class GenericsMain {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final String tag = "INT";

        Field field = resolve(tag);

        if (tag.equals("INT")) {
            /*
                In here I am using the "secret knowledge" that if tag equals INT, then
                field could be casted to Field<Integer>. But at the same time I see an unchecked cast
                warning at here.

                Is there a way to refactor the code to be warning-free?
             */
            Field<Integer> integerField = (Field<Integer>) field;

            foo(integerField);
        }
    }

    public static Field resolve(String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case "INT":
                return new Field<>(1);
            case "DOUBLE":
                return new Field<>(1.0d);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static <T> void foo(Field<T> param) {
        System.out.println(param.value);
    }

    static class Field<T> {
        public final T value;

        public Field(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid *unchecked cast* in the code above (marked with a long comment)?

Comment: Not directly. (Java does not support flow types.) You could use a visitor pattern here though.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java

Comment: @aioobe I would be really nice if you elaborate that with an example.

Comment: I'm not sure what the code is trying to achieve. Can you explain the problem statement?

Comment: @DenisKulagin, have a look at [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930808/how-to-avoid-large-if-statements-and-instanceof). Your `Field` would correspond to an `Animal`.

Comment: @aioobe Cool thing! It's just type is actually encoded via *what method to call* prior to runtime.

Comment: The question is why you need to receive a `Field<T>` in your `foo()` method instead of just a `Field<?>`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Good question. Actually it receives two arguments in full version of the code (of types): *Field<T>* and *T*. That's why.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, no way, since type parameter is bound to *declaration*. And what you want to do is to change static declaration based on the runtime value.

However, you can minimize area of unchecked cast by declaring parameterized method that adds type parameter

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> Field<T> asParameterized(Field<?> field) {
    return (Field<T>) field;
}
```

and then use

```
Field<Integer> intField = GenericsMain.<Integer> asParameterized(field);
```

Comment: Please read about heap pollution https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution.

Comment: Agreed, that's why compiler emits the warning, but this very case looks safe - there is exact 'secret' knowledge of what type parameter should be.

Comment: Well, if you trust on your 'secret' knowledge robustness, then I think it's allright. But you might have a bad day and perfectly do `Field<Integer> intField = asParameterized(field)` with `field` holding a double... Not very easy to fix and debug...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the annotation to do so. Use below annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Comment: That'll work, but my question is more about code design and how to avoid the warning architecturally.

Comment: You can't do it directly in java.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. Instead of dumb String tags, you can use a type which encodes the type information. See this blog post: http://blog.pdark.de/2010/05/28/type-safe-object-map/

```
public class FieldKey<T> {
    private String name;

    public FieldKey(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String name() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

plus changing the constructor of `Field` to `public Field(FieldKey<T> key, T value)`.

You still have to cast but compile time checks will make sure that they never fail.

Comment: And how are you going to make correctly parameterized declarations of FieldKey instances? :) I'm pretty sure, that something somewhere should be cast unchecked to break the loop

Comment: Please have a look at the code in my blog post; you can see the casts in the `get(TypedMapKey)` method. You can also move the cast into the key class: `public T get(Field<?> f)`. As I said, the main advantage of my approach is that you can use the type both on assignment and read and therefore make sure that the cast cannot fail.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers are fine, but I think there is not enough emphasis on *why* you're getting a warning and are casting.

You are *explicitly circumventing* the type system by performing an unchecked cast. By saying "I have information about this type that is not available to the compiler" - you are telling the compiler you know better.

That is of course a possible and reasonable use case: otherwise these casts would not be allowed, but a warning is good since it indicates you should be *really* sure what the type is.

**This makes perfect sense**. In fact, if you check libraries like GSON that do serialization they are [full of these warnings and supressions](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java#L60-L64).

Don't worry about your code - it's all fine. If there was a way to "trick" the compiler to not emit the warning that would have been a serious problem on the other hand :)