# instanceof considered harmful?

Tags: java, oop, architecture, refactoring

I am looking over some code that has heavy use of Java's `instanceof` operator.  I will fight the temptation to go into details, since this is a general question.  `instanceof` reminds me of of c++'s dynamic cast, and the advice I read about it, long ago, that if you think you need it, probably your model is off. Is this still the conventional wisdom?  Does it apply to Java's `instanceof`?

Comment: personal note , i am not quick to call any language feature evil or say that it should never be used.  yes, even goto.  I think instead there are certain patterns that should stand out when you see them, like an old geocities site with lots of blink tag, and say to the programmer "youd better be prepared to defend this choice".  Is frequent occurance of instanceOf one of these cases, or is it quite natural in some situations ?

Comment: I think of it like I think of reflection -- over-use is probably not good and suggests a consideration for re-design, but there are some situations where you just can't avoid using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is instanceof considered bad practice? If so, under what circumstances is instanceof still preferable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.  While `instanceof` certainly has its uses, heavy use generally indicates that your class design is deficient.

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's exactly the right answer. If you have to use a lot of `instanceOf` I would assume that your information flow has flaws. Usually any given part of the code should not need to ask what class it is being passed. Exceptions are of course possible and quite many. InstanceOf is a reflection functionality in a way and reflection always has to be used with care.

Comment: This answer is incomplete without some explanation why the use of `instanceof` indicates design flaws.

Comment: I have attended a course on programming languages that maintained that the use of `instanceof` is simply not object-oriented. Period.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, generics could/should be used to reduce the number of `instanceof` keywords. In that way only those few that are not known at compile time need to be checked. That said, `instanceof` is not something like `goto` - it doesn't mess up your control flow much (although it does introduce many extra variables if you're not careful).

I use `instanceof` regularly, but if there are many then I would consider it code smell. Trick is to come up with something better; if you can, then the use of `instanceof` is probably wrong. I would not know of a scheme to see if the use is good or bad for generic cases. The cast *after* `instanceof` is probably hurting more than the keyword itself.

Comment: actually, instanceof is often the wrong thing to use in an equals method, as you can create subtly wrong equals methods.  the best default for equals is to use `(getClass() == o.getClass())`.  only use instanceof if you _really_ need to support multiple types which are all "equal".

Comment: @jtahlborn: that's a good point, must have been brainwashed by the many equals() methods that use `instanceof`. Removed last part of answer.

Comment: yep.  unfortunately, that is the default implementation which is often used as a simple example or generated by an IDE.

Comment: @jtalborn, insteresting, but I would like to understand why getClass() is better than instanceOf. Could  you argue why?

Comment: @ejaenv - hard to describe it in a comment, see this article for an exhaustive answer: http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals.html