# having trouble setting up an array for my program

Tags: java

I am making a program for a library; the library contains different items such as book, videos, journals, ect...

I have a class called `item` with basic methods for every item in the library, and my classes for `book`, `video`, `journal` and all other items extend `Item`. I want to make an array to contain all of the items in the library so people can search for a specific item, it will find it in the array and display the info for that item.

The problem I'm having is that when I create an array of type `Item` I can only call methods of the `Item` class and I can't call the new methods I made for `book` in the `book` class or for `journal` in the `journal` class.

So I'm forced to have separate arrays for each of the different types of `Items`. 
Is there a way to have just one array that can call methods from all the different classes for each item?

You can see my code below; I have only attached the code for my `tester` class where the array is, let me know if you need to see the code for the other classes. I would appreciate any help.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Library{
  static String title;
  static String author;
  static int id;
  static int copies;
  static String date;
  static Book[] database = new Book[100];
  static Video[] database2 = new Video[100];
  static Journal[] database3 = new Journal[100];
  static CD[] database4 = new CD[100];
  static int count=0;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int i;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
      System.out.println("type the adjacent number to preform that process.\n1: Add an item\n2: Checkout an item\n0: Exit program");
      i=s.nextInt();
      switch(i){
        case 1:
          addItem();
          break;
        case 2: 

          break;
      }
    }while(i != 0);
    database[0].viewDetails();
    database[1].viewDetails();
    checkingOut();
    database[0].viewDetails();
    database[1].viewDetails();
  }
  public static void addItem(){
    int i;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
      System.out.println("type the adjacent number to add the item.\n1: Book\n2: Video\n3: Journal\n4: CD\n Type 0 to stop");
      i=s.nextInt();
      switch(i){
        case 1:
          addBook();
          break;
        case 2: 
          addVideo();
          break;
        case 3:
          addJournal();
          break;
        case 4:
          addCD();
          break;
      }
    }while(i != 0);
  }
  public static void addBook(){
    String title;
    String author;
    int id;
    int copies;
    String date;
    int count=0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the title of the book you want to add to the collection");
    title=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the author of the book you want to add to the collection");
    author=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the publishing date of the book you want to add to the collection");
    date=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the book you want to add to the collection");
    id=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the the number of copies that will be added into the collection");
    copies=s.nextInt();

    Book Book1 = new Book(date, author, copies, id, title);
    database[count] = Book1;
    count++;
  }
  public static void addJournal(){
    String title;
    String author;
    int id;
    int copies;
    String date;
    int count=0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the title of the journal you want to add to the collection");
    title=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the author of the journal you want to add to the collection");
    author=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the publishing date of the journal you want to add to the collection");
    date=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the journal you want to add to the collection");
    id=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the the number of copies that will be added into the collection");
    copies=s.nextInt();

    Journal Journal1 = new Journal(date, author, copies, id, title);
    database3[count] = Journal1;
    count++;
  }
  public static void addCD(){
    String title;
    String art;
    String genre;
    int id;
    int copies;
    int date;
    int count=0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the title of the cd you want to add to the collection");
    title=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the artist of the cd you want to add to the collection");
    art=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the release year of the cd you want to add to the collection");
    date=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the genre of the cd you want to add to the collection");
    genre=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the cd you want to add to the collection");
    id=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the the number of copies that will be added into the collection");
    copies=s.nextInt();

    CD CD1 = new CD(date, copies, id, title, art, genre);
    database4[count] = CD1;
    count++;
  }

  public static void addVideo(){
    String title;
    String director;
    int id;
    int copies;
    int date;
    String genre;
    int count=0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the title of the video you want to add to the collection");
    title=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the director of the cd you want to add to the collection");
    director=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the release year of the cd you want to add to the collection");
    date=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the genre of the video you want to add to the collection");
    genre=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the video you want to add to the collection");
    id=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the the number of copies that will be added into the collection");
    copies=s.nextInt();

    Video Video1 = new Video(date, copies, id, title, director, genre);
    database2[count] = Video1;
    count++;
  }

  public static void checkingOut(){
    boolean found=false;
    int idSearch;
    int i=0;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the book you want to check out");
    idSearch=s.nextInt();
    while(i<database.length && found!=true){
      if(database[i].getIdentificationNumber() == idSearch){
        found = true;
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    if(found==true){
      database[i].checkOut();
      System.out.println("There are "+database[i].getNumberCopies()+" copies left");
    }
    else{System.out.println("There is no book with that ID number!");}
  }
}
```

Comment: How would the array know the type of item it was working with if you put them all together?

Answer (score 2):

You could check the type and cast it to that type to gain access to the additional methods.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    for(Item item : itemList){
    if(item instanceof Book){
        Book book = (Book) item;
        book.someBookMethod();
     }
    }
}
```

though using `instanceof` is [considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9387955/2033671)

A better design would be to make `Item` abstract and create the methods common to all children, such as `add()`

```
public abstract class Item{
     public void add();
     public void viewDetails();
}

class Book extends Item{
    public void add(){
    //fun stuff
    }
    public void viewDetails(){
    //moar serious business logic
   }
}
....
public static void main(String args[]){
for(Item item : itemList){
    item.add();
}
}
```