# Issues on cast Object to Integer or String

Tags: java

I have to implement an interface IExecutable for a console menu application.The method that i am implementing is: **Object execute(Object o);** So i display the menu. I read from the console an menu option that could be an Integer or a String. On execution i have this error : 
**java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer**
The question is which is the best way make that conversion.

ConsoleMenu.java

```
public Object execute(Object o) {
        show();
        o = read();
        try{
            int choice = Integer.parseInt((String) o); // error on this line
            IExecutable menuOption = getMenuOptions(choice);
            if(menuOption != null){
                o = menuOption.execute(o);
                return o;
            }
              } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Invalid option"+ e.getMessage());       
        }

        return null;
    }

private static IExecutable getMenuOptions(int i){
    for(MenuOptions option :  options){
        if(option.getKey() == i && option.getIsActive()){
            return option;

        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static Object read(){
        String option = null;
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
                option = buffer.readLine();
                return option;

            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException " +e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = new Integer(1);
        ConsoleMenu menu = new ConsoleMenu("MATH OPERATIONS");
        menu.addMenuOption(new SubOption());
        menu.addMenuOption(new AddOption());
        i = (Integer) menu.execute(i);

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the error happens on the line that you indicated, and that the error is what you show?

Comment: The error is on the line `i = (Integer) menu.execute(i);`.  You should strongly reconsider your design, so that you don't have raw `Objects` which may be one of two different actual types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read from the console an menu option that could be an Integer or a String

If the user can either input 3 or X as a menu option, then you should not parse the value you get to an integer.

If you have the code for the MenuOptions, change its key property to a string not an integer.
If you do not, than a quick fix may be needed

```
private static IExecutable getMenuOptions(String i){
     for(MenuOptions option :  options){
        if(i.equals(option.getKey()+"")) && option.getIsActive()){
            return option;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

which may be called

```
IExecutable menuOption = getMenuOptions((String) o);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your error line:

```
if (o != null && o instanceof Integer){
    Integer choice = (Integer)o;

    //complete here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that o is really a String when you call `(String) o`

Below is a more expressive way of getting a String or Integer object from an Object

```
String.class.cast(o);
Integer.class.cast(o);
```

I think for this though you may also have to use the `instanceOf` operator to know which of the above to do. instanceOf is not a great way of doing this (See [Is instanceof considered bad practice? If so, under what circumstances is instanceof still preferable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan)) and some people will do anything to avoid it. In your current design I think you will have to include an instanceOf check

Comment: How is `class.cast()` an improvement over a straightforward cast?

Comment: I just think it reads better. You are actually saying in English that you are casting

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure that helps address the question, though.

Comment: The instanceOf will solve it I believe although as you say in your comment I would also recommend a redesign