# Make Java consider the most specific type when choosing method among overloaded methods

Tags: java, polymorphism

I would like to perform several operations based on the type of an object and without using `instanceof`. At first I was thinking of overloading methods based on types (as seen below), and thought that maybe Java would choose the method appropriately (based on most specific class of object).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TestA {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new A());
        list.add(new B());
        list.add(new C());
        list.add(new Object());

        TestA tester = new TestA();

        for(Object o: list)
        {
            tester.print(o);
        }
    }

    private void print(A o)
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    private void print(B o)
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    private void print(C o)
    {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

    private void print(Object o)
    {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
}

class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class C {

}
```

The output is:

```
Object
Object
Object
Object
```

However the output I'm after is:

```
A
B
C
Object
```

- Is there a way to make Java choose the method based on the most specific type of the parameter object?
- If not, what alternatives can I look at for such functionality, without the aid of `instanceof`
- I was actually trying to simulate the **visitor pattern** however it seems, what makes visitor pattern work is because of the double dispatch, which makes the parameter being "accepted" be in the correct type during function call, particularly, `visitor.accept(this)` in `class A` causes the function `visitor.accept(A o)` be called.
- I'm honestly against `instanceof` because I've read using it is bad practice; in this case, would it still be bad practice?

Comment: Isn't your `C` class extending `B` or `A`?

Comment: @RohitJain Nope. It's intended that C is another class altogether.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that you can't do that without `instanceof` check and appropriate casting. Still, let me take another look at your code.

Comment: You can't do that. But it looks like you have an XY problem. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Well it's calling `print(Object)` because you're passing an `Object`.

Comment: What is the objection to using instanceof in this situation? It seems to me that you want to pick code based on the class of an object that does not contain the method in question. Somehow, you are going to have to make choices based on object class. instanceof is the simplest, clearest, most direct way of doing so.

Comment: Why can't you use the visitor pattern here?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I guess `instanceof` would be the most appropriate for this situation. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Eric because modifying the classes in anyway is currently not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer considers that modifying given classes and their relationship is not an option.

> Is there a way to make Java choose the method based on the most
>   specific type of the parameter object?

Java compiler cannot cast this for you because maybe that's not what you want (in your case that's what you want, but maybe other people don't want this behavior and they would be no solution for them). Since you're passing an `Object` reference to `print()`, the compiler will call `print(Object)`.

> If not, what alternatives can I look at for such functionality,
>   without the aid of instanceof

You can wrap your `Object` with its type in a wrapper class, e.g.:

```
public class ObjectWrapper {
    private final Object object;
    private final int type;
}
```

This way you can safely cast to the type of the `Object` without using `instanceof`. Although this IMHO is more complicated than simply using `instanceof`, and actually it only creates your own `instanceof`...

> I'm honestly against instanceof because I've read using it is bad
>   practice; in this case, would it still be bad practice?

In programming, *nothing is always a bad practice*. Everything depends on the situation. In this situation I think you can use `instanceof` and do unsafe casting because the design requires so. And anyway, if `instanceof` operator exists in the language, is because it's used. If `instanceof` was *always* a bad practice, it wouldn't exist as part of the language. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan) and [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t302491-instanceof-not-always-bad-the-instanceof-myth.html).

> I was actually trying to simulate the visitor pattern however it
>   seems, what makes visitor pattern work is because of the double
>   dispatch, which makes the parameter being "accepted" be in the correct
>   type during function call, particularly, visitor.accept(this) in class
>   A causes the function visitor.accept(A o) be called.

Check my second link for cons on using the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 11):

Well my answer would be to make classes A,B and C implement a common interface.

And then each of them can have their own specific implementations of this interface.

This way, you can call the **same method for all the objects**(thus avoiding overloaded methods), and also **ensure custom functionality** based on the type of the object(i.e the class from which it was instantiated).

Comment: This is a good answer in general, but it involves changing the definitions of A, B, and C.  OP mentions in a comment that doing so is not an option for him.

Comment: @overthink, in that case, extend all three classes with wrappers that implement the common interface, and use those wrappers (/ that interface) instead of the A,B,C objects.  Again, not an option if A,B, and/or C are final classes, but viable otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Method Overloading is a compile time polymorphism, in your `for` loop , you have declared `o`  as `Object` and hence always print(Object o) will be called.

Solution:
Use Dynamic Polymorphism:

```
class A{

  void print(){
     System.out.println('in A');
  }
}

class B{

  void print(){
     System.out.println('in B');
  }
}
```

and the for loop

```
 for(Object o: list){
     o.print();
 }
```

Comment: This answer seems very on point to what I'm after. However is there a way to implement this **without modifying** the specified classes?

Comment: I am afraid not, you need to call the `print()` method on object `o`, and not pass it in a common method.

Comment: @Chad you WILL need to make the code change in the specified classes.

Answer (score 2):

Consider Visitor design pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern. Though it will need changes to A,B,C otherwise there is no other way.

Comment: This was actually the pattern I was kind of looking at (as specified in post), but I'm trying to **not** modify the classes.

Comment: then you will have to use instainceof :)

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Not forcibly. See my answer for a (bad) alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `instanceof` here.  It's simple and clear.

It's not like there is a *hard rule* to not use `instanceof`.  There are no hard rules :) Lots of use of `instanceof` may be a sign that you could change things to make the compiler do more work for you.  Whether that is actually worth doing needs to be looked at case by case.  In your case you mention you aren't able to change the classes in question, so it's not even an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.ank.says;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    class Base{
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("Base");
        }

    }

    class A extends Base{
        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    class B extends Base{
        @Override
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

    class C extends Base{
        @Override
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("C");
        }
    }



    public class TestPlayGround {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
              List<Base> list = new ArrayList<Base>();
                list.add(new A());
                list.add(new B());
                list.add(new C());
                list.add(new Base());

                TestPlayGround tester = new TestPlayGround();

                for(Base o: list)
                {
                    o.print();
                }

        }


    }
```

Output : -
A
B
C
Base

Comment: Hmmm you modified his code so much that it has nothing to do with the original question now...

Comment: I just gave an approach. But you are right this is probably not the best approach to go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

What pops out of my mind without use instanceof now is:

- Use a common interface for all of them to share a common method:

**Code:**

```
public interface YourInterface {
    public void doStuff();
}

public class A implements YourInterface {
    @Override
    public doStuff() {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
}

public class B implements YourInterface {
 @Override
    public doStuff() {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
}

List<YourInterface> list = new ArrayList<YourInterface>();
    list.add(new A());
    list.add(new B());

for(YourInterface e: list)
{
    e.doStuff();
}
```

- Use an Enum declaring an abstract method tha will be implemented by every type you have:

**Code:**

```
public enum YourEnum { 
    TYPE1 {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.print("Type 1"); 
    },

    TYPE2 {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.print("Type 2");         
    };

    public abstract void doStuff();
}

List<YourEnum> list = new ArrayList<YourEnum>();
    list.add(YourEnum.TYPE1);
    list.add(YourEnum.TYPE2);

for(YourEnum e: list)
{
    e.doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading above answer

One solution which i can suggest would be to use check the object type by using `o.getClass` and continue

However many better solutions are posted. I totally agree with what @krisna kishor shetty said

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view it's not the question whether or not use instanceof. The question is how to minimise the impact gained by this situation. So I would recommend instance adapter here in case there are several operations to deal with. That way you can at least avoid spreading that complexity all over the system:

```
public abstract class Adapter {
  public abstract void print();

  public static Adapter wrap(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof A) {
      return new AAdapter();
    }
    if (o instanceof B) {
      return new BAdapter();
    }
    return new ObjectAdapter():
}

public class AAdapter {
  public void print() {
    System.out.printLn("A");
  }
}
```

Then loop:

```
for (Object o: things) {
  Adapter.wrap(o).print();
}
```

Of course our Adapter will have a reference to the wrapped object as the method name implies. That way you get a coding model close to direct modification of those classes.