# How to determine type of derived class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Let's assume I have a super class called `animal`, and three sub classes respectively called `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Lion` that extend the `animal` class.
Then, I create an object each for the sub class and add them into an `ArrayList<animal>`.

When I am going through that list, how can I distinguish between a `Dog` or a `Cat` object as every object in the `ArrayList` is of type `animal`?

Comment: why do you need to distinguish them actually? typically, if you seriously want to learn some oop, you need to understand dynamic dispatch.

Comment: I am trying to tokenize a String input. 
My superclass is Token, and its subclasses are : parenthesis, number, operator. I put them in an arraylist. I need to distinguish them in order to perform specific function based on their type. Is their another way (a better way?) than using instanceOf for this case?

Comment: But don't they carry out the same action; `apply()` for example? You then override apply in each sub-class and simply call `theThing.apply()`. It applies it the proper way based on the specific instance type.

Comment: I have to detect some errors like mis use of parenthesis...so i need to know their specific type (i think).

Comment: there are some concepts you have to know first. if you use `instanceof`, you are solve problem `out of the box`, which is not oop. in oop, you need to make thing work `inside of the box`, which means you need to make the box react under certain condition. i have to admit, to me, the first idea is more nature and precise. but in oop, the logic is spread all over the world. in your case, you can do it in `double dispatch`.

Comment: Code should be first of all readable and correct. If instanceof improves code readability, it is fine for me.

Comment: @vojta It doesn't in this case.

Comment: @m0skit0 OK, I admit this is not the case.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `instanceof` operator:

```
if (animal instanceof Dog) {
   //something
} else if (animal instanceof Cat) {
   //something
} else if (animal instanceof Lion) {
   //something
}
```

However, you should think twice if you really need to use it. In most cases `instanceof` is a bad OOP practise.

Comment: Thank you very much! I looked every where for a solution but couldn t find thr right words. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan

Comment: @SangamChouchan Should I add anything to my answer? If no, accept it, please.

Answer (score 3):

The point of inheritance is that you don't need to know what the type of animal each object, when you call method that have to animal object then each subClass can implement this method as you want.

If you anyway need to know what the type you can use the keyword instanceof, but if you need to use it probably you did something wrong as OOP programing

Comment: Are you sure? Sometimes it is useful: I need to move all Moveable objects in my List of Moveable objects and paint only those objects that are also Paintable... I do not think I would have to keep two lists.

Comment: @vojta as you said, sometimes, oop is indeed counter intuitive. but unfortunately, a real oop doesn't need `instanceof`.

Comment: @vojta, I think the problem with that is SoC. Moving and painting aren't actually related. So, there should be separation between objects movement and painting. Choosing a list is really more of the issue. If you had all movables but only some paintable, perhaps a map of lists is the better option. This way you can get at the paintables when appropriate.

Comment: @vojta there is a reason why things like entity component systems exist. Your original approach is wrong with iterating through all movable objects and filtering out paintable ones.

Answer (score 1):

What Chief Two Pencils is trying to say in his comments is that you can use `instanceof` but in your situation there is a much better OOP design pattern to be used. For example, instead of distinguishing the object type, why don't you simply have a base method in `Animal` and override in each subtype? For example, `apply`. This way you can just call `animal.apply()` and the correct method for the type will apply.

Here's an example of what he means:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

abstract class Animal {
    abstract void apply();
}

class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    void apply() {
        System.out.println("Bark bark!");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    void apply() {
        System.out.println("Meeeeeow!");
    }
}

class Lion extends Animal {

    @Override
    void apply() {
        System.out.println("Rrrrrroar");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        animals.add(new Dog());
        animals.add(new Cat());
        animals.add(new Lion());

        // Dog
        animals.get(0).apply();
        // Cat
        animals.get(1).apply();
        // Lion
        animals.get(2).apply();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I didn't need to check which type it for the correct behavior to be invoked for each animal. This is what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: This expects there are no special arguments I need to pass to that action. What if I have a list of Animals and I need to put all Lions into some hypothetical `Cage` container and I need to give a `Toy` to all Dogs? (Let's assume we never put dogs into cages.) What should I do? I cannot have `lion.putMeIntoCage(cage)` in `lion.apply()`, because it would have no sense (putting into cage is not a method of lion. Lion class does not know there is such a Cage class at all) and I cannot have `dog.playWithToy(toy)`, because your `apply()` method has no arguments.

Comment: Keeping more than one list in my previous comment is not a solution. The list of animals can be passed by some calling class as an argument: `zoo.welcomeNewAnimals(animals)` for example. Any idea how to solve this without `instanceof`?

Comment: I'm not going to discuss *what if* because this is not the case. There are far more cases to not use `instanceof` than to use it. **Most of the** time you don't need to use `instanceof`, but some times it is the only solution. It exists for a reason (same as `goto` exists in C). Just make sure it is not a design problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you would have to use instanceof. You will find people discourage the use of instance of. Most people consider it a code smell. Why? Because the whole reason to use a typing system is so that you can treat different types as if they were the same. So in other words, if you collect a bunch of different types, based on their having similarities embodied in your base class, you should be satisfied with accessing each through that base class reference. If you are writing code that is checking each type and then doing different things, that means your type system is leaky.

For instance, consider some operation you might want to perform. Maybe you have to feed each animal (in a rescue center). You would define an operation in the base class like 'likes to eat' that would indicate what that animal wants. Each subclass would provide its own implementation of that method. But, from your main code, you could just iterate through the collection and call the method from the base class reference, not knowing the details of each. In this scenario, your model has afforded extension. Remember the adage: open to extension, closed to modification (attributed to Bertrand Meyer).

If you just throw a bunch of related objects into a collection and decide 'well I'll figure out what to do with each given the circumstances I find,' then you are not following this principle.

Answer (score -2):

Use instanceof to differentiate between different object types in the class hierarchy

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Inheritance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a list to hold all animals
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        //add animals
        animals.add(new Animal());
        animals.add(new Dog());
        animals.add(new Cat());

        for (Animal a:animals) {

            //Use instanceof to determine type of object

            if(a instanceof Dog){
                Dog dog = (Dog)a;
                dog.displayDog();
            }else if (a instanceof Cat) {
                Cat cat = (Cat)a;
                cat.displayCat();
            }else{
                a.display();
            }
        }


    }

}

class Animal{
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("This is a Animal");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    public void displayDog(){
        System.out.println("This is a Dog");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal{
    public void displayCat(){
        System.out.println("This is a Cat");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is *all* bad. Firstly, it's naive to do `displaySpecificType` methods. It goes against everything valuable in OOP. There's no benefit in designing classes like this. What you want is to be able to do `animal.display()` in *all* cases and expect the display to reflect the given type.