# How to check if object which is of a sub

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have an object which is modeled as such:

```
public class Template {
    private Form form;
    public Form getForm() { return form; }
}

public class SubTemplate extends Template {
    private Report report;

    public Report getReport() { return report; }

}

public class AnotherSubTemplate extends Template {
    private Sheet sheet;

    public Sheet getSheet() { return sheet; }

}
```

**My Goal:**

I want to know how I can check to see if the base object I'm dealing with `Template` in this case, is exercising polymorphism and is actually SubTemplate, so I can retrieve the report object from it?

Here is what I mean, something like this:

```
main() {
    Template t = something();
    if( t.getClass().isInstance(SubTemplate.class) ) {
        Report r = ((SubTemplate) t).getReport();
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work since the condition is always false. How can I accomplish my goal?

I realize this is some what of a hack but is what I'm asking possible? If so how to?

Comment: If you need to know what subclass you actually have, you're probably using polymorphism wrong.

Comment: See: [Is instanceof considered bad practice? If so, under what circumstances is instanceof still preferable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan)

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for the link but the code I'm dealing with seems to be older than me :) Not sure if redesigning it would be feasible. Right now I'm just testing

Comment: The correct expression using `Class.isInstance` for what you want is `SubTemplate.class.isInstance(t)`, but there is a much simpler `t instanceof SubTemplate`. `Class.isInstance` is meant for cases where you don't know which class you want to check against, and is usually only necessary in frameworks that do something generic, not in typical application code. And using `instanceof` is usually not a sign of good code.

Comment: So instanceof can work in the reverse order? Template -> SubTemplate and SubTemplate -> Template ? Like would both these checks work?

Comment: No, you need to make a distinction between an *instance* of a class, and a *class*. And note that a `java.lang.Class` **instance** is also an instance, that's why your original use of Class.isInstance compiled, but didn't work. (but note: `Class.class.isInstance(Template.class)` will return true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `instanceof` is meant to do:

```
Template t = something();
if (t instanceof SubTemplate) {
    SubTemplate sub = (SubTemplate) t;
    sub.getReport();
}
```

So after checking its type, you can cast it without expecting an exception.

Note that this is usually considered a code smell, see the comments for links to more information on why this is.