# Is it bad to have If-instanceof-statements in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, instanceof

```
   selectAction: (actionEvent) => {
        if (actionEvent instanceof Action1) { 
            // action1 body implementation
        } else if (actionEvent instanceof Action2) {
            // action2 body implementation
        } 
    }
```

The above code snippet reflects that different types of action which does different functionalities.I have used if and else condition to check action.

I feel it's not a good solution since I might have more actions in the future and my if-else-ladder will keep growing and I need to update my code again when there is a change.

Any idea on improving this specific scenario?

Comment: Interesting comment on that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2750773/6115238

Comment: It should be `actionEvent.select()`. Make it a method of your `Action` interface.

Comment: what are `action2` and `action1`? Are these actually supposed to be the same passed in parameter to the method (`actionEvent`)?

Comment: Where are `action1` and `action2` coming from, did you mean `actionEvent`?

Comment: *It depends,* as always. Is this list likely to grow? Or is it a specific limited list of things. E.g., if you're dealing with built-in types because you're writing a JSON encoder for instance, the list of types to work with is limited and this would be an appropriate approach. OTOH, if the types aren't limited by definition, then working with interfaces and `actionEvent.someAction()` instead makes a lot more sense. The details do matter here.

Comment: @Bergi Yh it was my mistake its `actionEvent` updated it

Comment: Please look up the `strategy pattern`. It's one possible way to counteract the nesting.

Comment: Please avoid `Is is bad` or `is it good` or `what better way to do X` questions. Bad how? Good how? In your case you want to increase maintainability. In some projects, the if-else-ladder is *good enough*. It's not inherently bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the approach of **duck typing** to avoid conditional scenarios. [Source](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/using-duck-typing-to-avoid-conditionals-in-javascript.html)

Have a method called `selection()` inside each type instance `Action1` and `Action2` so- on and use that to define the body/desired functionality you want to build. And simply call `selection()` method avoiding condition. So based on the instance of the type it will call the correct `selection()` method of the corresponding type

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with using `if`/`else` in TypeScript.

However, when you're using `instanceof`, the odds are that you probably have a better option available. In this case, almost certainly, the actions themselves should be responsible for doing what they do:

```
selectAction: (actionEvent) => {
    actionEvent.execute();
}
```

...or

```
selectAction: (actionEvent) => {
    const action = /*...derive action from actionEvent...*/;
    action.execute();
}
```

...or similar (or of course, use `actionEvent.execute()` directly instead of `selectAction`).

This is fundamentaly polymorphism, having different objects conforming to the same interface, and doing (potentially) different things when called.