# Assign a generic type to a variable of Class type

Tags: java, instanceof

```
// I would like to create a variable of Class type and assign a pattern into it like that:
Class clazz = HashMap<Long,HashMap<String, Semaphore>>.class; // does not work!

// I need it in order to be able later use it in .isInstance() expression, like:
if (clazz.isInstance(myVariable)) {
    // do something
}
```

, because the usual "instanceof" does not work either on pattern types.

With a simple types (non-pattern types) it works:

```
Class clazz = Long.class; // this works fine
```

How can I achieve what I want that is to assign a pattern and not a simple type?
If it is not allowed in Java, is there another proper way to test if the variable is an instance of a type defined as a pattern?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because of run time type erasure.

Comment: _I need it in order to be able later use it in .isInstance() expression,_ - Because of [type ereasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) you won't be able to validate the instance at runtime against the generic type. Further reading: [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Comment: You want also potentially read: [Is instanceof considered bad practice? If so, under what circumstances is instanceof still preferable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan)

Answer (score 1):

You can't check if you have an instance of `HashMap<Long,HashMap<String, Semaphore>>`.

Despite the syntax implying that `HashMap<Long,HashMap<String, Semaphore>>` is a single thing, that type actually means:

- A variable of this type will hold a `HashMap` (or null) at runtime
- And I want the compiler to stop me if I try to put in or take out a key which isn't a `Long`, and to stop me if I try to put in or take out anything which isn't a `HashMap` whose keys and values are of that specific type.

The bit between the `<>`s is purely a compile time hint. There is nothing there to test at runtime.

Provided the map isn't empty, you *can* check if it contains any keys or values which violate the type constraints.

But, aside from you only being able to do this if the map is non-empty, and contains non-null keys and values, it doesn't tell you if it is a *`HashMap<Long,HashMap<String, Semaphore>>`*, but rather that it is a `HashMap<? extends Long, ? extends HashMap<? extends String, ? extends Semaphore>>`.

You can safely consume things held in such a map, but you couldn't safely add to it, other than by re-adding keys and values which were already contained in that map, or null.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are erased after compilation.
So even this code that is valid will not help you further :

```
HashMap<Long, HashMap<String, Semaphore>> map = new HashMap<>();
Class<?> clazz = map.getClass();
```

`clazz` would refer `java.util.HashMap` "only" and not its generics.

About your requirement, if it happens that you have to write such a code and besides by checking the types of the generics :

```
if (clazz.isInstance(myVariable)) {
    // do something
}
```

I think that should rethink your logic.
Generics are mainly  designed to improve the type safety that mechanically reduces the requirement to `instanceof` test and downcasts.

> If it is not allowed in Java, is there another proper way to test if
>   the variable is an instance of a type defined as a pattern?

You could store the types specified in the generic instance by adding  `class` fields in the generic class. But as you use a built in type, you are stuck.
With your own class you could capture the information in this way for example :

```
public class Foo<T, U, V> {

    private Map<T, HashMap<U, V>> map = new HashMap<>();
    private Class<T> tClass;
    private Class<U> uClass;
    private Class<V> vClass;

    public Foo(Class<T> t, Class<U> u, Class<V> v) {
        this.tClass = t;
        this.uClass = u;
        this.vClass = v;
    }

}
```

So you can use `tClass`, `uClass`, `vClass` to perform the required checks.
But as said, going on into this way is probably not the best thing to do.