# How to figure out what object is in a abstract list?

Tags: java, list, loops, class, arraylist

I have an abstract class called sessions. Lectures and tutorials extend sessions. Then I have a class called enrollment which holds a list of sessions (Lectures & tutorials). How can I loop through the session list in Enrolment and return a list of Lectures only from the session list?

My next question is should I instead store 2 lists. One list of Lectures and one list of Tutorials, instead of 1 session list? This is because the sessions list is useless to me and I have to loop through it each time to get information about lectures and tutorials. Is there a way I am missing to get all the lectures objects? I am new to java.

```
public class Enrolment {

    private List<Session> sessions;

    public Enrolment() {
        this.sessions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public addSession(Session session) {
        this.sessions.add(session);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Session {

    private int time;

    public Session(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Lecture extends Session {

    private String lecturer;

    public Lecture(int time, String lecturer) {
        super(time);
        this.lecturer = lecturer;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Tutorial extends Session {

    private String tutor;
    private int tutorScore;

    public Tutorial(int time, String tutor, int tutorScore) {
        super(time);
        this.tutor = tutor;
        this.tutorScore = tutorScore;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enrolment newEnrolment = new Enrolment();

        Lecture morningLec = new Lecture(900, "Dr. Mike");
        newEnrolment.addSession(morningLec);

        Tutorial afternoonTut = new Tutorial(1400, "John Smith", 3);
        newEnrolment.addSession(afternoonTut);

        Lecture middayLec = new Lecture(1200, "Mr. Micheals");
        newEnrolment.addSession(middayLec);

        Tutorial NightTut = new Tutorial(1900, "Harry Pauls", 4);
        newEnrolment.addSession(NightTut);
    }
}
```

Comment: *should I instead store 2 lists. One list of Lectures and one list of Tutorials...*: maybe the question should be: *do you actually need the `Session` class itself?*

Comment: @ernest_k well both lecture object and tutorial object have time in it. And `Session` is basically something that isn't duplicating time (and it makes sense to have a abstract class).

Comment: Duplication is not *always* bad in *all* instances. Sometimes it's a good trade-off. If **all** the `Session` abstraction adds is the complexity you're facing right now, then maybe it should be questioned.

Comment: I agree with ernesk_k. Having an abstract class for good reasons doesn't mean that you will use it in every place even when you don't want this abstraction.  You will not create a list of `Object` because you can do it but because you need. Same thing for your list of `Session`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream the `sessions` list and use `instanceof` to filter the `Lectures` type objects

```
List<Lecture> l = sessions.stream()
                           .filter(Lecture.class::isInstance) 
                           .map(Lecture.class::cast)                               
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

By using `for` loop use two different lists for each type

```
List<Lecture> l = new ArrayList<>();
List<Tutorial> t = new ArrayList<>();
for (Session s : sessions) {
    if (s instanceof Lecture) {
        l.add((Lecture) s);
    }
      else if(s instanceof Tutorial) {
        t.add((Tutorial) s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, can you look at my second paragraph's question? Also can you also show me how to do it in a for loop or while loop? And also is the line you provided, is the time compexity of that O(n) or O(1)?

Comment: I do not think it will work without applying `map` to cast to `Lecture`.

Comment: @michalk So my question is in regards to the sessions list. Is there some kind of standard programmers use to get specific objects. The session class is useless by itself. It does nothing. I never need the session class, I always need the Lecture object and Tutorial Object. Is there a standard programmers use to only work with specific objects in a list like sessions

Comment: You could (and IMHO should) use `.filter(Lecture.class::isInstance) .map(Lecture.class::cast)` instead of `instanceof` and the `(Hard)` cast. Then you can also nicely pull this out into a utility method and call it like `List<Lecture> lectures = get(sessions, Lecture.class);`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should store in two lists, just like:

```
public class Enrolment {

    private List<Lecture> lectures;
    private List<Tutorial> tutorials;

    public Enrolment() {
        this.lectures = new ArrayList<>();
        this.tutorials = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addSession(Session session) {
        if (session instanceof Lecture) {
            lectures.add((Lecture) session);
        } else if (session instanceof  Tutorial) {
            tutorials.add((Tutorial) session);
        }
    }

    public List<Lecture> getLectures() {
        return lectures;
    }

    public List<Tutorial> getTutorials() {
        return tutorials;
    }

    public List<Session> getAllSessions() {
        ArrayList<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<>(lectures);
        sessions.addAll(tutorials);
        return sessions;
    }
}
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

> My next question is should I instead store 2 lists. One list of
>   Lectures and one list of Tutorials, instead of 1 session list? This is
>   because the sessions list is useless to me and I have to loop through
>   it each time to get information about lectures and tutorials. Is there
>   a way I am missing to get all the lectures objects?

You answered yourself to your problem.
When you start to write too complex/boiler plate code to make things that should be simple such as iterating on a list of objects that you have just added, it is a sign that you should step back and redesign the thing.

By introducing `Enrolment.addSession(Session session)`,
you introduced an undesirable abstraction :

```
public class Enrolment {

    private List<Session> sessions;

    public Enrolment() {
        this.sessions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public addSession(Session session) {
        this.sessions.add(session);
    }
}
```

You don't want to handle uniformally `Lecture` and `Tutorial` from the `Enrolment` point of view, so just don't merge them in the same `List` only because these rely on the same interface (`Session`).
Abstraction has to be used when it is required and not systematically because that is possible.
Don't you add all objects in a List of Object because all is Object ?  No.

Instead of, create this distinction both from the API method and from its implementation :

```
public class Enrolment {

    private List<Conference> conferences = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Tutorial> tutorials = new ArrayList<>();


    public addConference(Conference conference) {
        this.conferences.add(conference);
    }

    public addTutorial(Tutorial tutorial) {
        this.tutorials.add(tutorial);
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
Lecture morningLec = new Lecture(900, "Dr. Mike");
newEnrolment.addLecture(morningLec);

Tutorial afternoonTut = new Tutorial(1400, "John Smith", 3);
newEnrolment.addTutorial(afternoonTut);
```

---

Note that you could have a scenario where you need to manipulate uniformally Tutorial and Lecture for some processings but that for others you want to distinguish them.
In this case, you have some common  ways :

- `instanceOf` : easy to use but also easy to make a code brittle. For example, later you could add a new subclass in the Session hierarchy and without be aware of it, instances of this subclass could be included or excluded in some processing without that the compiler warns you.
- provide a abstract method that returns a boolean or an enum to convey the nature of the object (ex: `isLecture()`).  More robust than `instanceOf` since the compiler constraints you to override the method but it may also lead to error prone code if multiple subclasses are added and that the filters are not only on `Lecture` but `Lecture` and another type.  So I would favor this way while the filtering condition stays simple.
- define three lists : one for lectures, another for conferences and another that contains all of these that should be handled uniformally.   More complex way but more robust way too. I would favor it only for cases with complex/changing filtering conditions.

Comment: Exactly - I have the feeling most teachings of Java completely forget KISS as a principle. Most of the time you don't need inheritance and all that fancy stuff, keep it as simple as possible while still solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Lecture> l = newEnrolment.getSessions()
            .stream()
            .filter(s-> s.getClass().equals(Lecture.class))
            .map(session -> (Lecture) session)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

!!! Don't use *typeof*

Comment: How is this different than Deadpools's answer apart from slightly different filter expression? And what is `typeof`? I guess you meant `instanceof` ? And why do not use it?

Comment: Using of instanceof is a bad practice. That is only one difference. You could read as well> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750714/is-instanceof-considered-bad-practice-if-so-under-what-circumstances-is-instan . Sure, sorry, yes I ment instanceof

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from your question,

> This is because the sessions list is useless to me.

So, this is probably not the right place to have the list(?).

My preference would be to have

---

```
public interface Enrolment {
    public abstract addSession(Session session);
    public abstract getSessions();
}
```

---

And `List<LectureEnrolment>` and `List<TutorialEnrolment>` must be in their respective classes.(I have renamed `Lecture` to `LectureEnrolment` and `Tutorial` to `TutorialEnrolment`)

`main()` must have something like,

`Enrolment lectureEnrolment= new LectureEnrolment()`

`Enrolment tutorialEnrolement = new TutorialEnrolment()`

call the respective `addSession()` or `getSession()` depending on requirement.

Answer (score -1):

change `private List<Session> sessions;` to `public List<Session> sessions;` in `class Enrolment`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....
    var lecturesAndTutorials = newEnrolment.sessions.where(x => x.getType() == typeof(Lecture) || x.getType() == typeof(Tutorial));
    ....
}
```